# A way to display Latex style math equations in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, operating-system, calculator, tui, symbolicc++

**What I'm trying to do**

Im trying to create a terminal app to use as an advanced calculator and I want the equations to be formatted the way they are in latex and mathway.com both as input and output. I was considering using FinalCut to create the TUI but I am unsure how to actually output special charecters like sigma, delta, infinity etc. Even graphs.

**I would also like to ask how do Casio and Texas Instruments do the GUI on their calculator?**

[Equations in mathway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdbhF.png)

[Equations in markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SbIN.png)

I haven't tried a whole lot, because i am fairly inexperienced but I looking for directions I can go in.

Comment: "_I would also like to ask how do Casio and Texas Instruments do the GUI on their calculator?_" This sounds like a second question (you should generally stick to one question per question post), and also one that doesn't really seem like a good fit for Stack Overflow (see [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic)).

Comment: As for your main question about terminals, I'd wager it's difficult and will depend on what terminal emulator you're using. The answer might likely be no. You might be interested into looking into something called [sixel graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel), but I'm not sure if that's the right direction for you.

Comment: Maybe useful: a question on askubuntu.com: https://askubuntu.com/q/97542/1624654